# NLTK certainty measure?

Tags: python, classification, nltk, probability

In NLTK, if I write a NaiveBayes classifier for say movie reviews (determining if positive or negative), how can I determine the classifier "certainty" when classify a particular review? That is, I know how to run an 'accuracy' test on a given test set to see the general accuracy of the classifier. But is there anyway to have NLTk output its certainess? (perhaps on the basis on the most informative features...)

Thanks
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the NLTK implementation of Naive Bayes, but the Naive Bayes algorithm outputs probabilities of class membership.  However, they are horribly calibrated.

If you want good measures of certainty, you should use a different classification algorithm.  Logistic regression will do a decent job at producing calibrated estimates.

Answer (score 1):

`nltk.classify.util.log_likelihood`. For this problem, you can also try measuring the results by precision, recall, F-score at the token level, that is, scores for positive and negative respectively.